# Office 365 - "Show text predictions while typing" option disappeared

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365

Lately, I've noticed that Outlook for example, stopped suggesting text predictions while I'm typing.

Looking for this issue online, I got to find that there is an option for that under *File -> Options*, called "*Show text predictions while typing*".

The thing is that for some reason, this option doesn't exist at all in my Outlook. Obviously, it existed before, as I rememeber using this feature, but it's gone at some point.

I should mention that I have a paid annual subscription for Office 365, and all its apps are automatically updated.

Also, I've already run the repair feature of Microsoft 365, both for a quick repair and for the online repair, and nothing's changed.

Why don't I have this option at all? What can I do to get it back?

Comment: It is not working here either. I am still looking. Microsoft says the issue was fixed, but apparently not.

Comment: What‘s the build number of your Outlook? You can view the detailed version information via File > Office Account > About Outlook.

Comment: @YukiSun Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2305 Build 16.0.16501.20074) 64-bit

Answer (score 2):

The MS official article has been updated on June 6,2023 and its current status is "Investigating" which means the issue has already been noticed by the Outlook team and they are working on it at present. We can keep an eye on this article for any future status updates about this issue.

[Text predictions unexpectedly become unavailable and are missing in Outlook options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/text-predictions-unexpectedly-become-unavailable-and-are-missing-in-outlook-options-a4329021-66c0-4b2b-8b95-4e6009994272)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the subject of bug-report
[Text predictions unexpectedly become unavailable and are missing in Outlook options](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/text-predictions-unexpectedly-become-unavailable-and-are-missing-in-outlook-options-a4329021-66c0-4b2b-8b95-4e6009994272),
dating from April 10, 2023:

When you write email text in Outlook Desktop you expect to see suggested text but this feature has stopped working.

> When you check the Outlook settings the **Show text predictions while
> typing** option is missing:
>
> 1. While you're writing an email message, go to **File > Options**.
> 2. Check the **Show text predictions** while typing check box.

The status of this bug report is :

> **STATUS: FIXED**
>
> This issue was fixed for Current Channel on March 22, 2023. Monthly
> Enterprise Channel has been confirmed fixed on April 10, 2023.

Depending on which update channel you are on, this Office update may
arrive very soon on your computer.

Reference :
[Overview of update channels for Microsoft 365 Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/updates/overview-update-channels).

Comment: I see, thank you! But I'm not sure I understand when exactly to expect the next update to be installed on my PC... I ran a manual update for Office apps, but nothing has changed.

Comment: The fix was committed by the developer, but now it will pass through Quality Assurance and Beta testing before being released. For how long will that take, your guess is as good as mine.